# OleDbDatareader Decimal Issue

Tags: c#, localization, number-formatting, decimal-point, oledbdatareader

I have a tab-separated text file with some decimal values formated like that: 0,12 (comma as decimal separator).
I parse its contents to an OleDBDataReader via Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0, but when I look at the result, the value that should be decimal was converted to DateTime!

How to "force" my application to understand comma as decimal separator for numbers? 
Didn't work changing cultureinfo to en-US or any other.

```
public static OleDbDataReader CriarOleDbDataReader(string sCaminhoArquivo)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(sCaminhoArquivo);

        string format;

        string linha;

        if (fi.Extension.ToLower().Equals(".csv"))
        {
            string texto = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(sCaminhoArquivo).Replace(',', ';');
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(sCaminhoArquivo, texto);
            linha = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(sCaminhoArquivo)[0];
            format = "Delimited(;)";
        }
        else
        {                
            linha = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(sCaminhoArquivo)[0];
            format = (linha.Split('\t').Count() > 1) ? "TabDelimited" : "Delimited(;)";
        }

        DefinirSchema(fi, format);

        string cn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fi.DirectoryName + ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes';";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(cn);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [" + fi.Name + "]", con);
        OleDbDataReader dr;

        con.Open();

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        return dr;

    }
```

Field "IOF" is a decimal, its value in .txt file is 0,02 but it returns datetime.

```
dr["iof"]
{30/12/1899 00:02:00}
    Date: {30/12/1899 00:00:00}
    Day: 30
    DayOfWeek: Saturday
    DayOfYear: 364
    Hour: 0
    Kind: Unspecified
    Millisecond: 0
    Minute: 2
    Month: 12
    Second: 0
    Ticks: 599264353200000000
    TimeOfDay: {00:02:00}
    Year: 1899
```

Answer (score 1):

Just solved it.
I had to add some more lines in my schema.ini file, whose tries to determine de datatype for each column in the file. Got it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

These two babies did the trick:

ColNameHeader=True

MaxScanRows=0

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

"How to "force" my application to understand comma as decimal separator for numbers?"

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
decimal val = decimal.Parse("0,02");
```

The above code produces the decimal value 0.02.

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to convert AFTER de datareader is filled with data. I want it to fill on executereader with the correct values.

Comment: Then you need instead of `select * ` do something like this: `select functionConvertToDecimal(decimalField), anotherField, ... From...`

Answer (score 0):

You need one of these

1.

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("any culture where decimal separated by comma not the point");

  2.

If you're in US culture

This is pseudo-code, not exact syntax

```
decimal.Parse("0,02").Split(",").Join("."))
```

3.

Your file is tab-delimited. Load it using stream into datatable instead of using OleDb

Comment: 1 - Did not worked. 2 - As said before, the value must return in the correct format, so, late conversion is discarded. 3 - Datatable was the original solution and was working (badly, terrible performance). But when the file was over 300.000 lines, it threw an "OutOfMemoryException", so, datatable discarded.

Comment: Please read again. The message wasn't showing. Have you set the culture in which comma is decimal separator ? You can create a service and load your file to Sql Server and work from there